# Check for dbnull values in a list of objects

Tags: sql, powershell, object, replace, null

I have an object array that I retrieved from the `Invoke-SQLCmd`. Now I want to replace all the newlines in the `AboutPart` column.

Here is the code.

```
$rows = Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -inputfile "$queriespath\select_WHIProducts.sql" 
foreach($row in $rows) {
    if($row.AboutPart) {
        $row.aboutpart.gettype()
        $row.AboutPart = $row.AboutPart.replace("`r`n",' ')
    }
}
```

This works, however I am getting errors saying `dbnull` does not contain a method replace. I've done a check before the replace call and the nulls are still getting through according to the `getType()` call.

Comment: You could simply replace the newlines right in the SQL (`select replace(AboutPart, char(13)+char(10), ' ') as AboutPart from TheTable`), this way you would not have to bother in your Powershell script.

Comment: wow thanks let me try this

Comment: Alternatively look at the duplicate question, it shows how to deal with dbnull values in Powershell.

Comment: I'd probably just use `SELECT COALESCE(AboutPart, '') AS AboutPart`.  Get rid of the NULLs,

Comment: Thank you everyone you have solved my problem!!!